# Laravel SQL Connection - Artisan Migrate Works, but Application Can't Connect

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I'm an irregular Laravel user, and am trying to connect to a remote SQL database.

I've gotten the artisan commands working to create migrations and from the command line I can successfully connect to the database. But, when I try to load the application, the connection fails.

```
Could not connect to the database. Please check your configuration. error:PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'222.222.222.222' (using password: YES) in ... {file location}
```

What are artisan and the actual app framework doing differently that this connection would respond differently between the 2?

Here is the mysql connection in the database.php file:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '123.123.123.123'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'myuser'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypass'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '','strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'sslmode' => 'require',
        'options'   => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'certs/client-key.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'certs/client-cert.pem',
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => 'certs/server-ca.pem',
        ),
```

And this is the local environment file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=123.123.123.123
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=myuser
DB_PASSWORD=mypass
```

I am running the application locally, but the MySQl server is remote.

Comment: Is your remote database authentication is tunnel based ? if yes then you have to create tunnel and you'll need that open in order to use DB connection in the application.

Comment: It turns out that the root cause was that PDO doesn't like the cert generated by Google Cloud SQL.

Comment: glade its solved now.

Comment: You can answer your own question now.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the root cause was that PDO doesn't like the cert generated by Google Cloud SQL.